# Why Many of Saul's Descendants got Killed?

Tags: murder, samuel-shmuel-book-of, king-saul

Mefiboshet is crippled because he fall when Saul's descendants are running away from mass slaughter. Am I correct here?

Also when Abner is killed looks like there is more mass slaughter again.

But who would want to kill Saul's grand children? The only one with interests in their death is David and he doesn't like killing kings. I am not sure about that one.

Others have little incentive to kill Saul because David is not going to reward them anyway.

So who are killing Saul's descendants?

Not sure whether I should ask this in Christian forum (which don't care), history (which don't believe in bible), or here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Giv'onim wanted to kill him as revenge for him having killed them. See the full story in [Samuel 2 chapter 21](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08b21.htm).

Comment: There is no mention in the bible that Saul is killing Giv'onim (gibeonites). Also gibeonite is a small slave tribe and they're killing descendants of reigning king and the rest of israelites just watch?

Comment: @JimThio Rashi gives two possibilities: He either actually killed them when killing the kohanim in Nov (Nob), or he killed the kohanim who provided for them which caused their death. Saul was not the reigning king at the time; he was already dead.

Comment: Ishboshet, Saul's descendants were still alive. Ah killing the kohanim... That make sense. Saul did have tons of enemies.

Comment: Usually when a king died, his sons still have some power, being princes and all. Ishboshet is actually a king, himself, for example.

Comment: His son reigned for a short while, but after David started ruling the monarchy never returned to him.

Comment: Are you sure this is the reason though? That Saul's enemies are indeed the gibeonites?

Comment: He was their enemy. He, as far as I know, had neutral feelings towards them.

Comment: what do you mean neutral feeling? Saul had neutral feeling toward Gibeonites? Then he's not killing the gibeonites then.

Comment: His purpose in killing them was secondary to killing the kohanim, especially to Rashi's second explanation quoted above.

Comment: Rashi second explanation is strange. Why can't gibeonites pick another job? They're slave right? Now their master is gone, they're free. So why complain? Oh may be when Saul kill the kohanim he also mass murder those who worked for the kohanim? But that defy Samuel 2 that says that Saul's zeal for Judah make him kill the gibeonite.

Comment: They (cruelly) wanted revenge.